# Bundler won't install mysql2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

First of all I've gone through dozens of posting here on SO and google and haven't been able to find an answer.
I'm trying to install mysql2 with bundler and it won't do it.

Running on **Ubuntu Server 11.04 Natty**

Here's some background info:

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux]

gem -v
1.8.24

rails -v
Rails 3.2.5

$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.62, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
```

I have gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.11" in my Gemfile

When I do **bundle install** it goes through the process and it finishes successfully (**No Errors**) but it doesn't install mysql2. When I do **bundle show**, mysql2 is not listed.

I've tried a gazillion of things recommended here and on forums and still can't get mysql2 to install with bundler.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post **relavant** error messages *verbatim*.

Comment: you have to say what OS you are using too :)

Comment: Description updated. I don't get any errors. Bundle install will finish successfully with no errors, but mysql2 is not listed when I do  bundle show. I hope that helps to clarify.

Comment: Try manually doing `gem install mysql2 -v=0.3.11` and see if you get any errors that way.

Comment: gem install mysql2 -v=0.3.11
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.3.11
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql2-0.3.11...
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql2-0.3.11...

Received no errors. mysql2 still is not listed when I do bundle show.

Comment: Silly question, but do you have MySQL itself installed on your machine?

Comment: I do, running Mysql 5.2. I've updated the description.

Comment: Then this is not a problem with bundler, it's a problem with rubygems.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it's a problem with rubygems. If I do **gem list** then mysql2 (0.3.11) is in the list. I have the feeling that the fix is something very simple I just can't put my finger on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after many tries, reading, and pulling my hair out I found out what was the problem, so I'm posting it for those that might run into the same situation.

The reason why bundler wouldn't install mysql2 is because the gem was inside this **platforms** structure, see below:

```
platforms :mri_19, :mingw_19 do
  group :mysql do
    gem "mysql2", "0.3.11"
  end
end
```

So all I did was to move just gem "mysql2", "0.3.11" by itself to the top of the Gemfile and run **bundle install** and that did it! Now mysql2 is listed under bundle show and my rails application is running now.

Thanks every one that tried to help!

Comment: Fascinating, something I have never seen:" group :mysql ". I use in my file only "test, development, production and assets" groups to organize my rails project. Good job @wonitta!

Answer (score 10):

For mysql2 you need to install the dev files on your server.

try first:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Then check first your GemFile in your RoR App Dir - I have this line in my GemFile:

```
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.11'
```

run bundle:

```
bundle install
```

or try the command from Emily first then run bundle install:

```
gem install mysql2 -v=0.3.11
bundle install
```

I hope it helps

Comment: I already have the dev files:  
libmysqlclient-dev is already the newest version.  I ran through your steps above and mysql2 still not showing in the list when I do **bundle show**

Comment: sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev -- this worked for me. you rock dude!

Comment: `sudo yum install -y mysql-devel mysql-libs` if you're on a system with `yum`.

Comment: For me simply installing `libmysqlclient-dev` fixed the issue.