# "Please install the mysql2 adapter"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, redmine, mysql2

I am attempting to follow this [Redmine setup tutorial](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstallOSX). When I get to the point of starting the server, I type `sudo rails server` and I get the following error:

```
Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
```

The relevent section of my Gemfile reads:

```
....
if File.exist?(database_file)
database_config = YAML::load(ERB.new(IO.read(database_file)).result)
adapters = database_config.values.map {|c| c['adapter']}.compact.uniq
if adapters.any?
  adapters.each do |adapter|
    case adapter
    when /mysql/
      gem "mysql", "~> 2.8.1", :platforms => [:mri_18, :mingw_18]
      gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.11", :platforms => [:mri_19, :mingw_19]
      gem "activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter", :platforms => :jruby
...
```

and Gemfile.lock contains mysql2:

```
...
multi_json (1.5.0)
mysql (2.8.1)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
net-ldap (0.3.1)
...
```

and my database.yml file includes the following:

```
...
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: redmine
  host: localhost
  username: ****
  password: ****

development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: redmine_development
  host: localhost
  username: ****
  password: ****
  encoding: utf8
...
```

Running `bundle install` seems to succeed, but mysql2 is not listed in the output, `which mysql2` returns nothing, and `bundle show mysql2` returns `Could not find gem 'mysql2' in the current bundle.`

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the mysql2 gem, with apparent success each time.

I have read through descriptions of similar-sounding problems on other stackoverflow questions, but none of their solutions turned out to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get this error if `mysql2` is not included in the `Gemfile.lock` file that's generated by `bundle`. While the Gemfile is used to manage dependencies, the lock file is what is actually loaded by the rails app.

That's a more verbose Gemfile than I have seen before (I'm not generally familiar with Redmine)- where is this from? It doesn't appear to be from the most recent stable source. If you know you'll be using mysql2, I don't think there's any reason you need your Gemfile to parse your database config. For whatever reason, it's not properly reading the database.yml file.

Try adding `gem 'mysql2'` outside any blocks or loops and run `bundle` again.

Comment: I have tried adding `gem 'mysql2'` outside any `if`s and `bundle install`'ed again. No dice. Also, my Gemfile is hella longer than the little bit I just pasted. Is that a sign of a problem? I'm a n00b at this.

Comment: Also, mysql2 is included in the Gemfile.lock. Editing question to reflect this.

Comment: `mysql2` shouldn't be indented under `multi_json`. Try de-denting it in `Gemfile.lock` and see if it loads. If it does, you'll need to revisit your Gemfile to correct these dependencies.

Comment: Er, it's not. That was a typo. Sorry, I've fixed it.

Comment: See this --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004565/bundler-wont-install-mysql2